# C# Access registry of another user

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry, uac

I'm having a problem with the windows service I work on currently. Basically, I store some values in `HKCU` registry (from a GUI tool run as administrator) and from within that GUI I am starting a service. The service uses `SYSTEM` account to run, and I believe that's my problem - I can't access registry keys stored with my GUI tool inside the service, as it points to a different `HKCU`!

How can I **"redirect"** the service to use the `HKCU` of the user it was stored with? (Actually I can pass a user name to the service or `SID` if someone will point me how to retrieve it in my GUI, but I don't know what should I use to **"change"** the user to point to the correct one)

### EDIT 1:

I use a static class to access registry, it is used by both GUI and Service and the function to retrieve the base key is (`rootKey` is string variable holding the subkey name):

```
private static RegistryKey GetBaseKey(bool writable = false)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey reg = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
        RegistryKey rk = reg?.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", writable)?.OpenSubKey(rootKey, writable);

        return rk;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exceptions later
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have found `WindowsIdentity` class which can provide a handle (`AccessToken`) for current user, should I pass it as an argument to my service and use this handle to impersonate inside the service?

### EDIT 2:

I have done some stuff but it doesn't work. What I tried:

```
CurrentUserToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token; // to get current identity token
```

then with `ServiceController.Start` I added `CurrentUserToken.ToString()`
as an argument. Within my service I initialized `RegistryUserToken (IntPtr)` with the passed value and I'm stuck at:

```
WindowsIdentity RegUser = new WindowsIdentity(RegistryUserToken)
```

throwing exception:

> Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated

I tried the same with `AccessToken` of current instance of `WindowsIdentity` - same exception is thrown.

Can I at all go that way? Or should I try something different?

Comment: Show your code. How do you work with registry?

Comment: Added the "main" registry method, all other methods use it to obtain the subkey to work on.

Comment: You can simply run a Windows service under your user account.

Comment: I could, but it's possible to install the service (GUI installs/uninstalls, starts/stops the service) using one user account and configure (store required registry values) using a different account, later then launch it using that different account - this will still make those stored values inaccessible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I've managed to solve it going a bit different way. I've added SID variable to my Registry class and if it's not null then I open Users Registry Hive instead of HKCU. First I retrieve current's user SID (within my GUI application) using:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();
```

which I pass as an argument to my service and set it for Registry class.

Answer (score 6):

I can give you two options: impersonate that user if you have their credentials or use idea that HKCU is a symbolic link for one of the keys under HKEY_USERS. 
For impersonating you can see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C).
If you know the SID of that user, then you can find it in there. You can get the SID as so:

```
var account = new NTAccount("usernameThatYouNeed");
var identifier = (SecurityIdentifier)account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
var sid = identifier.Value;
```

I prefer impersonate. The second option is for case if you don't know that user's credentials. 
I dislike second option because it requires administrative rights to write in someone else's account.

Comment: Actually I believe I could use impersonation since I launch GUI first (as administrator), with the GUI tool i store those values (in HKCU registry) and from within that GUI I start the service, therefore I can (can I?) retrieve current user identity within GUI code and pass to a service, isn't that correct?

Comment: updated my question with what I've done and where I'm stuck, hopefully you'd help me on that.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to read registry of another user from a service. This is how I got it working, but in this case I know exact user name. Other answers here helped a lot. Username and path are whatever you need.

```
        NTAccount f = new NTAccount("yourUserName");
        SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
        String sidString = s.ToString();

        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey OurKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.Users;
        OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey(sidString + "\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\AppContainer\\Mappings", true);

        if (OurKey != null) { 
            foreach (string Keyname in OurKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
```